# How to split an ordered list into a list of lists before the next incidence of a number

Tags: python, list

I have an ordered list of incremental numbers that range from either 1-4 or 1-6. I would like to create a list of lists whereby they are split before the next incidence of 1.

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3 ,4]
list_of_lists = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

Comment: Seems a waste of memory. Why not just [4,4,6,4]?

Comment: They represent features in a GIS application and I need to assign a unique ID to each list using another attribute. Knowing this will take me to the next step.

Comment: I'm quite certain that it is the wrong approach, ... but OK.

Comment: Of course, I'm open to more efficient and pythonic approaches :) Help is appreciated.

Comment: ...then more context is needed. What is it you want to achieve? Can you edit your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A line is enough:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

result = [list(range(1, a + 1))
          for a, b in zip_longest(my_list, my_list[1:])
          if b == 1 or b == None]
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterate through `my_list` and create sublists everytime you hit a 1.

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3 ,4]
result = []
i = 0
while i<len(my_list):
    sub_list = [my_list[i]]
    i+=1
    while i<len(my_list) and my_list[i]>1:
        sub_list.append(my_list[i])
        i+=1
    result.append(sub_list)
print(result) 
# [[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```